# Gomoku on an infinite big board

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

I always used to play Gomoku in school on paper, and if we reached the edge of the field, we just put another one at that side.

And now I just saw that black can always win on 1 15x15 board. But what is about the way I used to play it? Is black also winning there, if both players play perfectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems to be an unsolved problem. On p. 60 of József Beck's book [*Combinatorial Games: Tic-Tac-Toe Theory*](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/discrete-mathematics-information-theory-and-coding/combinatorial-games-tic-tac-toe-theory), he states the following problem concerning "unrestricted $5$-in-a-row" (Gomoku on an infinite board):

> **Open Problem 4.1.** *Is it true that unrestricted $5$-in-a-row is a first player win?*

Answer (score 3):

There is discussion of this topic in volume 3 of *Winning Ways* (Berlekamp et al. 2003, pp 740–741). They discuss the general case of $n$-in-a-row on infinite boards.  A [strategy-stealing argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy-stealing_argument) shows that each game is either a draw or a first-player win.  It should be clear that if $n$-in-a-row is a first-player win, then so too is $m$-in-a-row for $m<n$, so the only real question is what is the largest $m$ that is a first-player win. They provide a proof that 9-in-a-row is a draw, and say  “T.G.L. Zetters… recently showed that the second player can even draw 8-in-a-row”.

Comment: Didn't thought that well about it, yeah ofc black can win then... but what about all this 9-in-a-row or 8-in-a-row... what is the board if you say that it is a first player win or a draw? Infinite board?

Comment: @platurt I now think I was wrong about Black being able to convert his $15\times15$ strategy into a strategy for the infinite board; details at [Strategy-stealing in Gomoku](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994408/strategy-stealing-in-gomoku)

Comment: This is an unsolved problem according to Beck's 2008 book on combinatorial games, see my answer.